# When should the Steady State Approximation be used?

Tags: kinetics

In class, I learned that we should use the steady state approximation when there are multiple slow steps or if the rate determining step is not known (shown on this [Chem Libre link](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/04%3A_Reaction_Mechanisms/4.12%3A_Steady-State_Approximation#:%7E:text=The%20steady%2Dstate%20approximation%20is,a%20duration%20of%20the%20reaction.&text=Thus%2C%20the%20system%20has%20reached%20a%20steady%2Dstate.)).

However, further research (another [Chem Libre link](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/03%3A_Rate_Laws/3.02%3A_Reaction_Mechanisms/3.2.06%3A_Steady_State_Approximation)) shows that the steady state approximation is only valid when the second step is much faster than the first step, causing the intermediate to be used up immediately.

But isn't this just the same as assuming that the first step is the rate determining step? Why use the steady state approximation at all if it is only valid in cases where we could just use the more simple procedure arising from assuming the first step is rate determining?

Comment: Why not to mathematically experiment with  sequential reactions and different ratios of their kinetic constant? You can then make your own conclusions. Ideal scenario is choosing of radioactive decay series.

Comment: @Poutnik assuming you do not calculate on an 12 kg sphere of 239-Pu... A less steady state is hard to find =P

Comment: @StianYttervik I have not said the steady state is found in all cases. :-P BTW, 12 kg 239Pu is outside of spontaneous decays series :-)

Comment: You can have a fast first step that is an equilibrium reaction and the a slow second step. This is described in the second cited textbook portion further down under enzyme catalysis.